# Is a Factory class still a Factory class if the objects it returns already exist?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-method

I can't decide what to name my class. So far I've labelled it up as a Factory, but I am not sure.

Here is the class. As you can see, it exists to return a concrete type of an Interface (`ResolveRegistrationIssue`) based on the argument supplied to the getter method (`ResolutionFamilyEnum`):

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean(name = "resolveIssuesFactory")
@ViewScoped
public class ResolveIssuesFactory implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{resolvePrimaryIssuesFactory}")
    private ResolvePrimaryIssuesBean resolvePrimaryIssuesBean;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{resolveSecondaryIssuesBean }")
    private ResolveSecondaryIssuesBean resolveSecondaryIssuesBean ;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{resolveTertaryIssuesBean }")
    private ResolveTertaryIssuesBean resolveTertaryIssuesBean ;

    public ResolveRegistrationIssue getResolutionBean(
            ResolutionFamilyEnum familyEnum) {

        //null safety
        if(null ==familyEnum) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The family which determines the Resolution Bean to be used may not be null.");
        }

        if (familyEnum.equals(ResolutionFamilyEnum .PRIMARY)) {
            return resolvePrimaryIssuesBean;
        } else if (familyEnum.equals(ResolutionFamilyEnum .SECONDARY)) {
            return resolveSecondaryIssuesBean;
        } else if (familyEnum.equals(ResolutionFamilyEnum .TERTERY)) {
            return resolveTertaryIssuesBean;
                    } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not determine the correct Resolution Issue bean for the provided family.");
        }
    }
```

Now, I understand that a Factory class accepts arguments which define the entity to be **developed** and then **delivered** (returned).

However in my case, my entities are already developed, as they are EJB references. Thus this method only delivers them.

So is this still a Factory?

Comment: Look at [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) and consider the naming of the classes in the examples.

Comment: The internal implementation doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from typing up this question myself.  I have entities which are stored in an identity map so each distinct ID only has one instance; the first time you call the factory method with a certain ID you would get a new instance (which gets added to the identity map) and each successive time you would get the same instance already loaded from the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be more related to the [Service Locator](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/ServiceLocator.htm) pattern.

While you are not using JNDI as the registry, your class is acting as one. This is not a flyweight pattern though. It doesn't look like this implementation is meant to save memory. It is meant to look-up instances to "services" based on an Enumeration.

Comment: The "create if not created but otherwise return reference" nature of this pattern makes me feel that this is the most natural fit. Thanks